# Android Audio Control to forward and Reverse

Tags: android

I am creating a custom Audio Player. So far I am able to add features such as Audio streaming, volume control, Duration, Progress bar etc. I have to add feature where user can touch a slider and jump audio to skip some part. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you have to use `mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);`.

```
     seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
            else if(mediaPlayer!=null && !isPlaying)
            {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }



        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
}
    });
```

Comment: Seems to me the `else if` is not needed. Also, if you want to get the progress you can do `seekBar.getProgress()`. Thanks for the code, anyway.